# How would I compute the gravitational radiation from two masses in an elliptical orbit?

Tags: orbital-motion

I am looking at a research project that was suggested to me in another question. I would like some guidance. Thanks

Comment: Have you tried [Wikipedia's page on the 2-body problem in GR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-body_problem_in_general_relativity#Gravitational_radiation) ?

Comment: You could read a textbook to find some formulas, write some code and come back if you have a problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This undergraduate paper](https://rrubenza.github.io/project/p413_gws/RR_PHY413_GW_Paper.pdf) uses General Relativity to derive the formula for the power radiated in gravitational waves, does the calculation for a circular orbit, and discusses its verification by the [Hulse-Taylor binary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hulse%E2%80%93Taylor_binary).

You should be able to generalize it for an elliptical orbit. If you get stuck, the elliptical calculation was done by Peters and Matthews in [this research paper](https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRev.131.435). But try it yourself first!

You could also look at additional aspects, such as the radiated momentum and angular momentum; the angular distribution of these radiated quantities; the frequency distribution of these quantities; and the evolution of the orbital parameters.

If this seems too complicated, you could use [this formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadrupole_formula) to estimate the metric perturbation caused by orbiting black holes. LIGO can measure perturbations of order $10^{-21}$, so you could look at how far away from Earth a black hole system can be for us to be able to detect its gravitational waves.

Comment: Thank you so much for the information. I have got a lot of exams coming up so I will try and start working on this on the weekend. I will come back if I have an issue. Thanks again!